# Writing process memory without WriteProcessMemory

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to write another process memory without using `WriteProcessMemory()` function.

I'm calling `VirtualAllocEx()` to pass data to my thread with `CreateRemoteThread()`.

```
WriteMemoryInfo* m = (WriteMemoryInfo*)VirtualAllocEx(
    hProc, 
    NULL, 
    1024, 
    MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, 
    PAGE_READWRITE
);

m->addr = FinalAddress; // Problem
m->data = Data;         // Problem
m->length = Size;       // Problem

HANDLE threadID = CreateRemoteThread(
    hProc, 
    NULL, 
    0, 
    (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)RemoteThread,
    m, 
    NULL, 
    NULL
);
```

The problem is, I can't write to the new created memory with `VirtualAllocEx()` as it doesn't belong to my process. The solution would be to use `WriteProcessMemory()` on this memory but it's the function I'm doing.

How can I initialize this memory (`m` variable) without `WriteProcessMemory()` ?

Comment: Create a named memory mapped file, write the information in there, have your remote thread open that file and read the information. Of course, it makes no sense not to use `WriteProcessMemory`.

Comment: why you not want use `WriteProcessMemory` ? in what problem here ? also you can create section (file mapping) - map it first in self process, initialize data, than map it in remote process

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - we not need *named* section here. remote thread not need open it (also - where code of this thread will located ?) we can(and need) map this section yourself in remote process. also i think that code of this thread also need be inside section (if it not in already loaded to process dll, in what i doubt)

Comment: @RbMm How do you map it into a remote process? Is that using a supported API?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan [`ZwMapViewOfSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwmapviewofsection) supported not less that code injection

Comment: Tell us your reason for NOT wanting to use WriteProcessMemory and we can better answer this question.

Comment: `WriteProcessMemory()` is often wrongly detected by antivirus (with mine at least)  as malicious.

Answer (score 2):

`CreateRemoteThread()` and `VirtualAllocEx(`) will be categorized as just as risky as `WriteProcessMemory()`, if you're using these you might as well use `WriteProcessMemory()` also.

The `lpParameter` argument for `CreateRemoteThread()` takes a pointer to a variable to be passed to the function.

If you don't want to use `WriteProcessMemory()` you can start the process with a command line argument, pass whatever you want to use for `lpParameter` as a command line argument.  It will exist in the target process but the process will just ignore it.

You can then pattern scan for this variable to get the address and then pass this address as the `lpParameter` variable.

This neat trick was shared with me by my friend timb3r.